# Making Image Slider on Storyboard Issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipagecontrol

I've made a basic image slider and it is working fine via adding subview's. However I should make it in storyboard. I'm running almost the same code but it is not running.

I just want to make 3 images slider.

So please can anybody tell where would be my issue?

```
- (void)run{

pageNumber =3;

_scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
_scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_scrollview.pagingEnabled = true;
_scrollview.bounces = false;
_scrollview.delegate = self;
_scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
_scrollview.layer.cornerRadius = 2;

_pgcontrol = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
_pgcontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1];
_pgcontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1];
_pgcontrol.numberOfPages = pageNumber;
_pgcontrol.currentPage = 0;
[_pgcontrol sizeToFit];

UIImageView*im_ = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
im_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
im_.clipsToBounds = true;
im_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31900.png"];

UIImageView*im1_ = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
im1_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
im1_.clipsToBounds = true;
im1_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31901.png"];

UIImageView*im2_ = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
im2_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
im2_.clipsToBounds = true;
im2_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31902.png"];

[_scrollview addSubview:im_];
[_scrollview addSubview:im1_];
[_scrollview addSubview:im2_];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

int page_ = (int)round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);

if (page_== pageNumber-3) {
    NSLog(@"page3");
}

else if (page_ == pageNumber-2){
    NSLog(@"page2");
}

else if (page_ == pageNumber-1){
    NSLog(@"page3");
}
_pgcontrol.currentPage = page_;
}
```

/////
Old code
/////

```
- (void)imageCreater{

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

CGRect svrect_ = CGRectZero;
svrect_.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height/3.1*2;
svrect_.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width/3*2;

CGPoint svcenter_ = CGPointZero;
svcenter_.x = self.view.center.x;
svcenter_.y = self.view.center.y+65;

CGSize svconsize = CGSizeZero;
svconsize.height = svrect_.size.height;
svconsize.width = svrect_.size.width * 3;

CGPoint pgconcenter_ = CGPointZero;
pgconcenter_.x = self.view.center.x;
pgconcenter_.y = svcenter_.y + (svrect_.size.height/2) + 40;

CGRect btnrect_ = CGRectZero;
btnrect_.size.width = 250;
btnrect_.size.height = 50;

CGPoint btncenter_ = CGPointZero;
btncenter_.x = self.view.center.x;
btncenter_.y = self.view.bounds.size.height-65;

_backgroundimageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:_backgroundimageview];

_scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
_scrollview.center = svcenter_;
_scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_scrollview.contentSize = svconsize;
_scrollview.pagingEnabled = true;
_scrollview.bounces = false;
_scrollview.delegate = self;
_scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
_scrollview.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollview];

_pgcontrol = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_pgcontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1];
_pgcontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1];
_pgcontrol.numberOfPages = 3;
_pgcontrol.currentPage = 0;
[_pgcontrol sizeToFit];
_pgcontrol.center = pgconcenter_;
[self.view addSubview:_pgcontrol];

UIImageView*iv_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31900.png"];

svrect_.origin.x += iv_.frame.size.width;

UIImageView*iv1_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv1_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv1_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv1_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31901.png"];

svrect_.origin.x += iv1_.frame.size.width;

UIImageView*iv2_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv2_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv2_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv2_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31902.png"];

[_scrollview addSubview:iv_];
[_scrollview addSubview:iv1_];
[_scrollview addSubview:iv2_];
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are exactly getting using storyboards? Did you drop UIScrollView on your user interface file and link it to the File Owner?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman My issue is I'm not getting any images. Yes I have linked the interface link.

Comment: let me post the answer for you. Give me a minute.

Comment: you need horizontal scroller or vertical?

Comment: I need it like paging which is horizontal I think.

Comment: posted the answer please check and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)run
{
    // If you are using story board and user interface then you don't need to initialize scroll view.
    _scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _scrollview.pagingEnabled = true;
    _scrollview.bounces = false;
    _scrollview.delegate = self;
    _scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    _scrollview.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    _scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*3, _scrollview.frame.size.height);

    // Same for Page control you dont need to initialize it
    _pgcontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1];
    _pgcontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1];
    _pgcontrol.numberOfPages = pageNumber;
    _pgcontrol.currentPage = 0;

    UIImageView *im_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_scrollview.frame.size.width*0),0,_scrollview.frame.size.width,_scrollview.frame.size.height)];
    im_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    im_.clipsToBounds = true;
    im_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31900.png"];

    UIImageView*im1_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_scrollview.frame.size.width*1),0,_scrollview.frame.size.width,_scrollview.frame.size.height)];
    im1_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    im1_.clipsToBounds = true;
    im1_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31901.png"];

    UIImageView*im2_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_scrollview.frame.size.width*2),0,_scrollview.frame.size.width,_scrollview.frame.size.height)];
    im2_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    im2_.clipsToBounds = true;
    im2_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31902.png"];

    [_scrollview addSubview:im_];
    [_scrollview addSubview:im1_];
    [_scrollview addSubview:im2_];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int page_ = (int)round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);

    if (page_== pageNumber-3) 
    {
        NSLog(@"page3");
    }

    else if (page_ == pageNumber-2)
    {
        NSLog(@"page2");
    }

    else if (page_ == pageNumber-1)
    {
        NSLog(@"page3");
    }
    _pgcontrol.currentPage = page_;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry it is not working. Also this is vertical not horizontal. No images

Comment: This is not vertical because I am changing the x-coordinate of the images and placing them into the UIScrollView. If it is easy to share the code then please do it. It will be really easy to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean I share the project?

Comment: Yes if you can because I have tried the above code and it is working fine for me.

Comment: in your old code I noticed that you are assigning the rect to the images you are adding in scroll view but you are not setting it in your new code as same as you are doing it in the old code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67333/discussion-between-can-and-adeel-ur-rehman).

Comment: Can you send me the project in which you implement storyboard? Please upload somewhere and send me the link. I will download and check

Comment: @CAN sorry I was just busy. I am going to look into the code and let you know.

Comment: @CAN first of all I have seen your code you send to me. There were lot of mistakes in that. First is the image you mentioned in the code were not in the project that is why you were not shown any image when the simulator load the app. Second is the components you drop on interface file where not properly aligned using auto layout or resizing mask. Other than that the code in the answer works fine.

Comment: @CAN you can download the code using this link [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20020679/TestTest.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20020679/TestTest.zip) Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: sorry there is one issue which is when I change the page from page two to one it is showing that it is in page three while it is in page one. How I can fix that? Also when I put it on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus the page is scrolling up and down.

Comment: let me look into that.

Comment: @CAN I tested the code on my end which I send it to you and it is working fine on both 6 and 6+ with no up and down scrolling.